# Multi-factor models on equity long-short hedge funds

Tags: regression, hedge-fund

I am seeking papers that use quantitative techniques such as regression or multi-factor models for equity long-short funds. I am interested in understanding equity long-short hedge funds' behavior and exposure to various factors, such as sectors, regions, countries, styles, etc.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Quantopian Risk Model](https://www.quantopian.com/papers/risk) whitepaper. It goes over implementation details of the multi-factor risk model used by Quantopian to analyze long-short equity strategies.

The QRM includes 11 sector factors, and 5 style factors: momentum, size, value, short-term reversal, and volatility.

(Full disclosure, I work at Quantopian)

Comment: may I ask you one more question?
I am running regression on a equity long/short fund against s&p 500 10 sectors indices (tech, industrials, financials, etc.).

I have this fund's historical sector exposure and it has exposures to consumer staples and consumer discretionary. However, when I run regression, the p-values associated with the sectors are very high. Why would the OLS model not capture these exposures? What should I do to capture them?

Comment: @JunJang it might be worth creating a new thread for this question. My understanding is that, in general, p-values are not enough to evaluate exposure. You should also take beta into account, and evaluate beta's consistency over time.